# Linq 2 XML not returning element based in attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
      <City>Acampo</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
    <Employee>
      <EmpId>5</EmpId>
      <Name>Kenneth Lowrey</Name>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Phone Type="Home">555-555-3477</Phone>
      <Phone Type="Work">444-123-2557</Phone>
      <Address>
        <Street>6026 Amberwoods Drive</Street>
        <City>Boca Raton</City>
        <State>FL</State>
        <Zip>33433</Zip>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </Address>
    </Employee>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I have the following Console Application code...

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String strPath = @"C:\XMLExample\Employees.xml";
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(strPath);

        var empquery = from e in xEle.Descendants("Employee")
                       select new
                           {
                               name = e.Element("Name").Value,
                               homephone = (string)e.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type").Value=="Home" ? e.Element("Phone").Value : "",
                               workphone = (string)e.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type").Value=="Work" ? e.Element("Phone").Value : "",
                           };

        foreach (var e in empquery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}'s home phone is {1} work phone is {2}", e.name, e.homephone, e.workphone);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to separate the home and work phone numbers in my query expressions.

However I'm only able to get the home phone number..

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: e.Element only gets first match.  Use Where like Arturo suggested or use the plural Elements() to get all the 'Phone' tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element()` method returns only the first element matching the specified name. So for each `Employee` you will only gets the first phone (Home).

A better approach is use `Elements()` method to gets ALL elements matching the specified name and then filters by attribute `Type` value:

```
var empquery = from e in xEle.Descendants("Employee")
                select new
                {
                    name = e.Element("Name").Value,
                    homephone = (string)e.Elements("Phone").Where(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    workphone = (string)e.Elements("Phone").Where(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Work").FirstOrDefault().Value
                };
```